# SML List Structure Implementation Of Important Functions

Tags: sml

I have a midterm in 2 days and my professor announced that in order to practice, we should write the implementation of the important functions for lists. I managed to find the list of important functions for the list structure on http://www.standardml.org/Basis/list.html but this site only contains the function name and the type for the function. I was wondering if anyone knew of a web site which had the implementation of the function as well as the type. I've attempted to search this but I wasn't able to find anything helpful. I am a not that comfortable with higher order functions and currying so it would be helpful to me to see a few examples of how the important list functions are implemented so that I understand the basics. So if anyone knows of a link which has the implementation code for the important list functions, I would really appreciate it if you can share it.

Thank-You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SML/NJ's basis library implementation is open source. You can see it at http://smlnj-gforge.cs.uchicago.edu/scm/viewvc.php/sml/trunk/system/Basis/Implementation/?root=smlnj, and list.sml (the implementation of the basis list functions) is at http://smlnj-gforge.cs.uchicago.edu/scm/viewvc.php/sml/trunk/system/Basis/Implementation/list.sml?view=markup&root=smlnj.

You would probably do well to try each function first before you look at its implementation, though. They follow similar patterns, so even if the first one or two are difficult for you, after a few examples it will get easier.